# Keras with Tensorflow: Use memory as it's needed [ResourceExhaustedError]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

So I'm trying to tain my CNN with mutilple datasets and it seams that when I add enough data (such as when I add multiple sets as one or when I try to add the one that has over a million samples) it throws a `ResourceExhaustedError`.

As for the instructions [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1538), I tried adding

```
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.3
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

to my code but this doesn't seam to make a difference. 
I see 0.3 after printing out `config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` so that part seams to be ok.

I even threw in a `config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True` for good mesure but it doesn't seam to want to do anything but attempt to use all the memory at once only to find that it isn't enough.

The computer I'm trying to use to train this CNN has 4 GTX1080 Ti's with 12gb of dedicated memory each.

EDIT: I'm sorry for not specifying how I was loading the data, I honestly didn't realise there was more than one way. When I was learning, they always had examples where the loaded the datasets that were already built in and it took me a while to realise how to load a self-supplied dataset.

The way I'm doing it is that I'm creating two numpy arrays . One has the path or each image and the other has the corresponding label. Here's the most basic example of this:

```
data_dir = "folder_name"

# There is a folder for every form and in that folder is every line of that form
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(data_dir, '*', '*')):

    # the format for file names are: "{author id}-{form id}-{line number}.png"
    # filename is a path to the file so .split('\\')[-1] get's the raw file name without the path and .split('-')[0] get's the author id
    authors.append(filename.split('\\')[-1].split('-')[0])
    files.append(filename)

#keras requires numpy arrays 
img_files  = np.asarray(files)
img_targets = np.asarray(authors)
```

Comment: This usually happens when there are not enough RAM on the GPU(s) to load the whole dataset (or a batch of it). Would you please post your code as well? Further, if your image files are on the hard disk, have you tried using [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) class and its [`flow_from_directory`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_directory) method? Plus, you should [properly set up your model](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-run-a-keras-model-on-multiple-gpus) to be able to train it on multiple GPUs.

Comment: I will not post my entire code because a lot of it irrelevant and because it's long and would take more time to go through it than would be worth it for the majority of the people here but I'll gladly post specific parts of the code if you wish. 

I'll try to use ImageDataGenerator. Let's see what happens. Thanks for the response

Comment: After looking into ImageDataGenerator, I realised that I'm actually doing it myself manually in the code. I tested it and it seams to work, plus using Keras' one won't wok for me as I need to split up each image rather than simply resize it

Comment: Please post your generator and your fit method.

Comment: @The-IT Then just post the relevant parts like the network architecture (i.e. layers used), `fit_generator` method and the generator itself.

Comment: Also please post the code for what you consider "add data".

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you're not using a giant `batch_size`?

"Adding data": honestly I don't know what that means and if you could please describe exactly, with code, what you're doing here, it would be of help.

The number of samples should not cause any problems with GPU memory at all. What does cause a problem is a **big `batch_size`**.

Loading a huge dataset could cause a CPU RAM problem, not related with keras/tensorflow. A problem with a numpy array that is too big. (You can test this by simply loading your data "without creating any models")

If that is your problem, you should use a `generator` to load batches gradually. Again, since there is absolutely no code in your question, we can't help much.

But these are two forms of simply creating a generator for images:

- Use the existing `ImageDataGenerator` and it's `flow_from_directory()` methods, [explained here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)
- Create your own coded generator, which can be:

  - A loop with `yield`
  - A class derived from [keras.utils.Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/#sequence)

A quick example of a loop generator:

```
def imageBatchGenerator(imageFiles, imageLabels, batch_size):
    while True:
        batches = len(imageFiles) // batch_size
        if len(imageFiles) % batch_size > 0:
            batches += 1

        for b in range(batches):
            start = b * batch_size
            end = (b+1) * batch_size

            images = loadTheseImagesIntoNumpy(imageFiles[start:end])
            labels = imageLabels[start:end]

            yield images,labels
```

> Warning: even with generators, you must make sure your batch size is not too big!

Using it:

```
model.fit_generator(imageBatchGenerator(files,labels,batchSize), steps_per_epoch = theNumberOfBatches, epochs= ....)
```

### Dividing your model among GPUs

You should be able to decide which layers are processed by which GPU, this "could" probably optimize your RAM usage.

Example, when creating the model:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    createLayersThatGoIntoGPU0

with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    createLayersThatGoIntoGPU1

#you will probably need to go back to a previous GPU, as you must define your layers in a proper sequence
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    createMoreLayersForGPU0

#and so on
```

I'm not sure this would be better or not, but it's worth trying too.

See more details here: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-run-a-keras-model-on-multiple-gpus

Comment: 1: Yes. I have tried resizing the batches a number of times and even size of 2 raises the same error. 
2: I mean this in the most literal way possible. I have a lot of data, and I started off with it training of about 600 samples which seamed to work save for that it was over fitting which I figured I would change by loading more samples from data sets. When I get to even 1000 samples this error occurs. 
3: loading the data seams to be no issue for me although I guess that depends on what you mean by that. I "load the data" by creating two numpy arrays with the labels and the classes... CONT

Comment: And even when creating these arrays with over a million samples (a label and a corresponding class) there seams to be no problem. What gets fed into the model are images from a generator function that does a bit of pre-processing on the images including splitting them up and passing each part individually. Will attempt to use ImageDataGenerator. Thank you for your response

Comment: After looking into ImageDataGenerator, I realised that I'm actually doing it myself manually in the code. I tested it and it seams to work, plus using Keras' one won't wok for me as I need to split up each image rather than simply resize it

Answer (score 0):

The `ResourceExhaustedError` is raised because you're trying to allocate more memory than is available in your GPUs or main memory. The memory allocation is approximately equal to your network footprint (to estimate this, save a checkpoint and look at the file size) plus your batch size multiplied by the size of a single element of your dataset.

It's difficult to answer your question directly without some more information about your setup, but there is one element of this question that caught my attention: you said that you get the error when you "add enough data" or "use a big enough dataset." That's odd. Notice that the size of your dataset is not included in the calculation for memory allocation footprint. Thus, the size of the dataset shouldn't matter. Since it does, that seems to imply that you are somehow attempting to load your entire dataset into GPU memory or main memory. If you're doing this, that's the origin of your problem. To fix it, use the TensorFlow [`Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) API. Using a `Dataset` sidesteps this limited memory resources by hiding the data behind an `Iterator` that only yields batches when called. Alternatively, you could use the older `feed_dict` and `QueueRunner` data feeding structure, but I don't recommend it. You can find some examples of this [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data).

If you are already using the `Dataset` API, you'll need to post more of your code as an edit to your question for us to help you.

Answer (score -1):

There is no setting that magically allows you more memory than your GPU has. It looks to me that your inputs are just to big to fit in the GPU RAM (along with all the required state and gradients).
you should use the `config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True` but not in order to get more memory, just to get an idea of how much memory you need per input length. start with a small length, see with `nvidia-smi` how much RAM does your GPU take and then increase the length. do that again and again until you understand what is the maximal length of inputs (batch size) that your GPU can hold.

Comment: I'm not trying to get more memory, I'm trying to get Tensorflow to not try and use all the memory at once and rather only the amount of memory it needs to process the current samples. What I'm getting from you here is that my batch sizes are too big for the size of my dataset, right?

Comment: Tensorflow by default takes ALL the memory in the GPU in order to secure it for later use. Most of the time this is the desired behavior because it guarantees that you have the maximum available memory throughout all your session. In case you want tensorflow to allocate only what needs to actually run, simply set 'allow_growth = True' as mentioned before. Now, if you are setting this to True and still see that all the RAM is taken - it means that all the RAM is needed, if not more!